# When using clang (for C++0x) in XCode 4.2 how can I see symbols in the profiler?

Tags: iphone, profiler, llvm, symbols, clang

I've configured my XCode project to build with "Apple LLVM compiler 3.0", (clang).  When I attempt to profile the app in the CPU sampler in Instruments, I'm not seeing any symbol names from my binary.  Is this just not yet implemented?

Note 1: that I do see symbols from the system and Frameworks, such as OpenGL, and Quartz, etc...
Note 2: XCode build number is 4D199.

Comment: I've used C++ build with LLVM 3.0 fine with instruments. Are you stripping the symbols or not building the dsym for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instruments will use spotlight's indexes to locate the Dysm for a given binary. It is possible that you have disable indexing for the folder containing your dsym. Verify that, reindex, and give it another shot.